# How to rename multiple files?

Tags: software-recommendation, nautilus, rename

I'm trying to move some files to another folder that already contains older files with the same name. `Nautilus` asks me every time to rename the duplicate files and they're too much to rename them individually.

Is there any way like (Keep Both) in Windows  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use PyRenamer, a Python based tool for massive file renaming